# What is the optimal mongodb model for a collection with a large number of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a table on my website that displays information about sporting events that can be bet on. Each event looks like this in mongodb...

```
{
    bookmaker: 'Bet365',
    event: 'Man U vs Man City',
    bet: 'Man U',
    sport: 'Football',
    odds: '2.2',
    rating: '95.12',
    date: '08/08/2021',
    time: '15:00',
    availability: '352.25',
    link: 'example.com'
}
```

or I could use this object model instead, this would mean a lot less objects, but the data that is needed is more imbedded and filtering by bookmaker is much harder.

```
{
    event: 'Man U vs Man City',
    sport: 'Football',
    date: '08/08/2021',
    time: '15:00',
    link: 'example.com',
    bookmakers: [
        {
            bookmaker: 'Coral',
            markets: [
                {
                    bet: 'Man U',
                    odds: 2.2
                },
                { 
                    bet: 'Draw',
                    odds: 3.4
                },
                { 
                    bet: 'Man City',
                    odds: 3.00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            bookmaker: 'Bet365',
            markets: [
                {
                    bet: 'Man U',
                    odds: 2.3
                },
                { 
                    bet: 'Draw',
                    odds: 3.45
                },
                { 
                    bet: 'Man City',
                    odds: 3.00
                }
            ]
        },
        // MORE BOOKMAKER OBJECTS...
    ]
}
```

There are about 100 different bookmakers and 100,000 different events, and 10 sports. The user can filter the results based on bookmaker, or sport. I have a few questions about the best way to model and query a database like this:

1. When the user firsts loads the table, I want to display the top 10 events (events 1-10 from the 100,000) based on 'rating', if they go to the next page it should then show them results 11-20 (again based on 'rating'). Would this be to slow? What is the best balance for speed, given the data has to be found as fast as possible but also sent to the client in an efficient manner?

Currently the database is modelled so that each bookmaker has its own document in mongodb, and then the document has a seperate array of events for each of the 10 sports. This gives me about 100 documents, each with 10 embedded arrays of events. Each document in the collection looks like this...

```
{
    football: [
        // event object,
        // event object,
        // event object,
        // ...
    ],
    horse_racing: [
        // event object,
        // event object,
        // event object,
        // ...
    ],
    // ... 8 more sports per document
}
```

2. This seems like it would be slow when the user hasn't filtered the results, as the database would need to look through every document, and every embedded array and then filter these results by 'rating' to get the correct events to display based on the page the user is on. However, if the user has filtered the results by 'sport' or 'bookmaker', this model seems like it would be very fast to query. So my question is, is this model optimal for what I'm trying to do given that 80-90% of the time, the user would have filtered the results by 'sport' or 'bookmaker' or both?

Sorry there are a lot of questions, but I know pretty much zero about modelling a database, and I thought somebody who knows a lot about this, might be interested or willing to help. If you need any more info, please ask. I've tried to provide as much detail as possible, without making it overly long and complicated. Thanks

Comment: Don't use dynamic field names, i.e. better use `{ [
{name: "football", events: [{event object}, {event object}, ...]},
{name: "horse_racing", events: [{event object}, {event object}, ...]}
]}` Then you can easily add more sports.

Comment: I am not familiar with sports betting. So, what is the relationship between the bookmaker and an event (e.g., an event is associated with one bookmaker, etc.)?

Comment: No one event is linked to every bookmaker. So instead of modelling the event object like the one above, you could just have a bookmakers array of objects, where each object gives details about the bookmaker and the odds on that bookmaker. I've edited the question to show what this would look like. Would this be better?